# Cannot assign to property: 'outputs' is a get-only property

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, protocols

I'm trying to implement a VC using MVVM Inputs Outputs approach, but I'm getting compiler errors when I try to bind reassigning the outputs closures in the view controller. I do understand that 'outputs' is a get-only property, but its properties are get set.

How could I solve this problem?

```
protocol ViewModelOutputsType {
    var didReceiveServiceError: ((Error) -> Void) { get set }
    var reloadData: (() -> Void) { get set }
}

protocol ViewModelType {
    var outputs: ViewModelOutputsType { get }
}

final class ViewModel: ViewModelType, ViewModelOutputsType {
    var outputs: ViewModelOutputsType { return self }

    //output
    var didReceiveServiceError: ((Error) -> Void) = { _ in }
    
    var reloadData: (() -> Void) = {}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    private func bind() {
        //this gives the compiler error
        viewModel.outputs.didReceiveServiceError = { [weak self] error in

        }
        //this gives the compiler error
        viewModel.outputs.reloadData = { [weak self] in

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please include `SearchViewModelOutputsType`

Comment: you included `ViewModelOutputsType` protocol

Comment: thank you, it was just a typo, it was intended to be ViewModelOutputsType everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `ViewModelOutputsType` can either be a value or reference type. If it is a value type, then mutating any of its properties mutates the instance itself. You can resolve the issue by making the protocol class constrained and hence guaranteeing it to be a reference type.

```
protocol ViewModelOutputsType: class {
    var didReceiveServiceError: ((Error) -> Void) { get set }
    var reloadData: (() -> Void) { get set }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't mutate `ViewModelOutputsType` because it could be a struct because of the protocol. I think if you have `protocol ViewModelOutputsType: class {` it would allow you to mutate the properties